# What happens if you delete the contents of the EFI partition?

Tags: high-sierra, efi

So, I was playing around with the `diskutil` command.  Then I thought of mounting the EFI partition. It mounted successfully and I viewed its contents. When I right-clicked on a file I saw an option to move it to the trash.

So I was thinking: what will happen if you delete the contents of the EFI partition? Will they be recreated when you wipe the entire disk and reinstall MacOS?

PS: I would also like to know where the EFI partition is located?